# MS Word change background/watermark size

Tags: microsoft-word

I have bought an MS Word template which has a particular region with different background color.

I have really tried hard to change the size of that region, but have found no success in doing so.

The file is shown here [image: following is the screen shot].

The problem is with light-grey region (below the dark grey 'Lebenslauf' region).
I want to move the lower edge of this light-grey region upwards so that its height is reduced.

But there is no selectable edge or anything that I can select/move. Also in the layout of themes I couldn't find anything. The file is attached here.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lJ53jMx4bSESnCiNmmo_rKmRYRC9hfmR/view?usp=sharing

I will be very thankful to know how can I reduced the height of the middle  region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The troublesome region is situated in the header of the Word file. To access it, double click the *Lebenslauf* band. The **header and footer** menu will open. You can acces the band, you can resize it, even delete it. After you're done, click the **close** button.

Comment: I never realized a region of this much size (beyond header's own dimensions) can be added to header. Great help indeed, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Regions much larger can be added to the header as well.